# Strawberry perl on Windows won't run anymore

Tags: windows, perl, cpanm

Suddenly, my Strawberry Perl on Windows 10 says "This app can't run on your PC."
I have a 64-bit Lenovo laptop.
I reinstalled the latest 64-bit Strawberry perl, and it still doesn't run in the same way.
Then I installed the 32-bit version.  Now perl.exe seems to work, but if I run cpanm I get:

> Errno architecture (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int-10.0.19041.388)
> does not match executable architecture
> (MSWin32-x64-multi-thread-10.0.19041.388) at
> C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Errno.pm line 12. Compilation failed in require
> at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/File/Temp.pm line 152. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/File/Temp.pm
> line 152. Compilation failed in require at cpanm line 32. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at cpanm line 32. Compilation failed in
> require at cpanm line 499. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at cpanm
> line 499.

What is wrong?

Here's my system:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
System Name L18-0486
System Manufacturer LENOVO
System Model    20LES15000
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  LENOVO_MT_20LE_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3rd
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 1800 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a 64-bit version of Perl to access a file installed using a 32-bit installation of Perl.

Comment: Please paste a pic of your system properties, like shown in https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-windows-10.  I'd remove the 32-bit Perl and try reinstalling a new 64-bit version.  Perhaps your original 64-bit perl.exe just got corrupted.

Comment: Pasted.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that's irrelevant. You're using a 64-bit version of Perl to access a file installed using a 32-bit installation of Perl.

Comment: Not irrelevant, it's proof that it's really a 64-bit OS.  But, yeah, you have a mix of files installed.  I think you'll need to remove the Perl install(s), and check for other files, like a cpan dir, and start over with a fresh 64-bit install.

Comment: @jimtut, Re "*Not irrelevant, it's proof that it's really a 64-bit OS.*", which is 1) irrelevant, and 2) already known since it's impossible to run a 64-bit program on a 32-bit OS

Comment: if I was using windows for perl I would uninstall strawberry and install [activeperl](https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/downloads/) which a bit more flexible and choose perl 5.26.

Comment: Manu, did you ever get this working?

Comment: Thank you very much for following up on this.  I did uninstall everything, and reinstalled Perl.  Now the program runs, but I am having other issues with packages which I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065248/strawberry-perl-lyx-perl-modules-and-windows-10